# pyinstaller changes python script's running path

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am new to pyinstaller and just been trying to make an .exe using it. My script is determined to locate the absolute folder path where the script resides and do some operations on the other files in the same folder.

Snippet of this implemention is as follows:

```
import os
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

def rename_pdf_files():
    # Get the directory of the script
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print(f'Checking in directory: {script_dir} for PDF files... ')
    # Change the working directory to the script directory
    os.chdir(script_dir)

    # Get a list of all the PDF files in the directory
    filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir('.') if filename.endswith('.pdf')]
........
```

the script runs fine when I run it directly from python file. For example, if it runs inside a path ***E:\Python Programs\theBoringCodes\PDFRenamerToTitle*** the script shows `Checking in directory: E:\Python Programs\theBoringCodes\PDFRenamerToTitle for PDF files...` and goes on the rest of the operations.

However, running through the .exe made by pyinstaller, the script is shows that `Checking in directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI210962 for PDF files...` although .exe is located at ***E:\Python Programs\theBoringCodes\PDFRenamerToTitle\dist*** folder.

How to resolve this issue so that the .exe file checks inside the folder it is located? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get the path of the executed file once "compiled" with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274894/get-the-path-of-the-executed-file-once-compiled-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: @Alexander, Thanks a million!!! This is just the perfect solution!!