Pyinstaller --onefile does not show Chrome window launched with selenium
I wrote a simple script with Selenium and I added a second file (gui.py) with a gui where when I click a button the simple script in Selenium is launched. I installed chromedriver and the path variable is correctly updated.
When I run the gui.py, I see the button, I press it, I see the Chrome window appearing and the script working on the Chrome window. When I create the .exe using pyinstaller --onefile gui.py the gui with the botton is correctly showe, but I do not see anymore the Chrome window appearing.
Here the code of my gui.py:
    import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import subprocess
import shutil


def run_script():
    try:
        # I used it to troubleshooting the correct path to the script.py file
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            script_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "script.py")
        else:
            script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "script.py")

        result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, script_path], capture_output=True, text=True)

        if result.returncode == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Script ran successfully!")
            print("Script ran successfully!")
            print(result.stdout)
        else:
            error_message = f"Script failed with return code {result.returncode}:\n{result.stderr}"
            messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message)
            print(error_message)
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"An unexpected error occurred:\n{e}"
        messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message)
        print(error_message)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Run Script and Upload CSV")

run_button = tk.Button(root, text="Run Script", command=run_script)
run_button.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()

The file called is script.py:
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


# I need this dataframe for working in as many chrome windows as many rows I have. Ignore it if you do not find it relevant

df = pd.read_csv('list.csv')
df.cp = df.cp.astype(str)


service = Service()
website = 'https://google.com'


for i, j in df.iterrows():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

    driver.get(website)

    time.sleep(3) #....the rest of the code...

I checked the PATH variables, I tried with --one directory instead, but I cannot find the reason why the gui.exe does not launch a new chrome window visible to the user

probably because it isn't launching a chrome window at all.  Post your code

Actually it launches correctly chrome when I run gui.py from pycharm. It is in the .exe file that I make some mistakes. I updated my question with the code, I hope it is helpful

@Alexander the behaviour with the .exe file is the following:

The gui is correctly displayed,
I click on the run button,
it does not launch the Chrome window and it duplicates a new gui (so I see two gui),
if I click again the "run" button a third gui is displayed.. And all of this in loop.


Hopefully this answer might shed some light on what the issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274894/get-the-path-of-the-executed-file-once-compiled-with-pyinstaller/74275052#74275052

@Alexander I tried and the current working directory in the dist folder, as it should be. Why the chrome window is not displaying and the gui is duplicating?

If you made changes to your code please modify your question to reflect those changes.
